# Create an aspx page (with content) after pressing a button. ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Good Morning/Afternoon/Evening. I need to know if it's possible to create a new aspx with content after pressing a button, i managed to create a aspx page after pressing a button but i don't know how to add the specific div that i want in the new page.

Here's the code that i have so far :

```
private void BtnCreateNode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var path = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\";
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }


            string FilePath = path.ToString() + "Test" + ".aspx";
            try
            {
                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(FilePath))
                {
                    byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(""); /*The div should be here...*/
                    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
                }

                using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(FilePath))
                {
                    string s = "";
                    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(s);
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

If i try `byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(MyDiv.ToString()); /*The div should be here...*/` my output is `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl` instead of the intended code, anything i can do to solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: You're programmatically writing to an .aspx file, yes? And an .aspx file is just a text file, isn't it? So why are you using `byte[]` at all? I'm confused by this question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to place a div at a specific place in the page. The first thing I would do is get the ID of the specific div, make sure it has `runat="server"` and then place that div (based on its ID property) where you want it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry if i wasn't clear enough, what i'm trying to do crate a new aspx file from another aspx file (the code above is for that) but i can't seem to add the div that i'm trying input in the file that's being created, Thanks!